# How to Create RxJava Observables in Android

Tags: observable, rx-java

I have some confusion about multiple ways of creating and using the Observables:

- How to Create `Hot`/`Cold` Observable in Android?
- How to Use `Hot`/`Cold` Observable in Android?
- Create Observables with Backpressure?
- Create Observables which emit value on subscribe as well as trigger a specific event manually ?

I am quite new in RxJava stuff, started just couple of weeks ago. So far what I have learned leaves these mysteries still unsolved.

Comment: *So far what i have learned these are **mysteries** that are still unsolved.* Have you read the documentation about `observers`? http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html

Comment: yup , gone through whole documentation previous weekend, there is not a single code example to make your own `hot/cold` Observable , just theory , you can check

Comment: Because these are general reactivex docs, not java specific.

Comment: In most cases you want to avoid hot observables, as that invariably introduces the chance that you'll miss some events.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos sometimes , scenario demands for some strange solutions, hot observables if i'm correct `run onNext as soon as it's created` , and cold observable `wait for it to be subscribed` , and as far as i know creating Observable using `.create()` allow you to make cold observable , but this question was to confirm my concept

Comment: @mallaudin , java specific or not , i didn't found any ` java code` example so far to understand and use these concepts in code

Comment: I guess you don't mean creating them from scratch. There were a bunch of questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+observable

Comment: @Mr.Z For hot observables, look into subjects.

Comment: I don't know why people hated so much this question , despite of giving any proper answer

Comment: ....man, it started up and died immediately, wtf. -_- they hated this question because "it lacks research", but I think it's just this reactive elitism that's been going on

Comment: Sometimes people don't like what they don't understand

Answer (score 1):

1. The same way as in any other platform.
2. The same way as in any other platform.
3. Use RxJava 2; Flowables have backpressure, Observables do not. If you absolutely need to ue RxJava 1, read the docs on each operator to see if it supports backpressure.
4. It depends on your use case. More detail needed.

Have you actually tried playing around with Rx on android?

Comment: Thanks for replying , (1) , (2) , in android i can't seem to find any code example so far , i was expecting some code examples

Comment: I will not recommend any specific tutorial, but "android rxjava example" will give you tons on any search engine. (and yes, this kind of response is discouraged on SO).

Comment: There are a stupid number of bad examples using `Observable.create()` in RxJava1 though.